# how to write setdata() in qsqlquerymodel(QAbstractItemModel)?

Tags: c++, qt

I've made `myModel` using **inheritance** (`QSqlQueryModel`) and I
 insert column into it. I want insert data of type `QString`, but I don't know how to do.

`QSQlQueryModel` is read-only model. To make it read-write, you must subclass it and reimplement `setData()` and `flags()`.

I want to override these two methods and here is what I've done so far:
**dialog.cpp:**

```
this->model = new myModel(this);
model->setQuery("SELECT * lists");
model->insertColumn(3);
model->setHeaderData(3, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("string"));
qDebug() << model->setData(model->index(0,3),"string",Qt::EditRole);
// column add, column set data using setdata()
ui->tvGameList->setModel(model);
```

**myModel.h:**

```
class myModel : public QSqlQueryModel
{

    Q_OBJECT

public:
    myModel(QObject *parent = 0);
    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

};
```

**myModel.cpp:**

```
#include "mymodel.h"
#include <QSqlQuery>

myModel::myModel(QObject *parent): QSqlQueryModel(parent)
{
}

Qt::ItemFlags myModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    Qt::ItemFlags flags = QSqlQueryModel::flags(index);
    if (index.column() == 1 || index.column() == 2)
        flags |= Qt::ItemIsEditable;
    return flags;
}

bool myModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role = Qt::EditRole)
{
    if (index.isValid() && role == Qt::EditRole)
    {
        // I don't know here
        emit dataChanged(index, index);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why are you inheriting from `QSqlQueryModel`? What behavior of that model are you trying to change?

Comment: I want set data in model index. 
model->setData(model->index(0,3),"string",Qt::EditRole);
so, I want reimplement setdata() function.

Comment: You don't need to reimplement `setData` at all. Just call existing `setData` from the place where you wish to use your class. It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

See Qt examples, setData must call SQL UPDATE statment as usually SQL.

```
Qt::ItemFlags EditableSqlModel::flags(
    const QModelIndex &index) const
{
 Qt::ItemFlags flags = QSqlQueryModel::flags(index);
 if (index.column() == 1 || index.column() == 2)
     flags |= Qt::ItemIsEditable;
 return flags;
}


bool EditableSqlModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int /* role */)
{
if (index.column() < 1 || index.column() > 2)
    return false;

QModelIndex primaryKeyIndex = QSqlQueryModel::index(index.row(), 0);
int id = data(primaryKeyIndex).toInt();

clear();

bool ok;
if (index.column() == 1) {
    ok = setFirstName(id, value.toString());
} else {
    ok = setLastName(id, value.toString());
}
refresh();
return ok;
}

bool EditableSqlModel::setFirstName(int personId, const QString &firstName)
{
 QSqlQuery query;
 query.prepare("update person set firstname = ? where id = ?");
 query.addBindValue(firstName);
 query.addBindValue(personId);
 return query.exec();
 }
```